# AL wants Assembly Reference to DAL, why? Better Architecture needed

Tags: c#, architecture

When I try my pocos from the application layer, it screams for a missing reference to DAL (where the entity framework belongs).

Not so surprising because my guides so far reference it as base class.
BUT! It's like this..

> "Hi application X! Yeah nice, I
>   understand. I will give you the paket,
>   but you have to take the data from DAL
>   yourself, ok?".

There have to be abetter way to code? 
Isn't it a big point of n-tier that AL and DAL are completely isolated to communicate through BL..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have introduced this by using a type from your DAL as a base-class in the BL; in some ways, maybe the problem is, then, that the BL is using (and exposing) too much about the DAL, when maybe that might be better addressed via IoC.

Either way, either live with it, or expect a **big** refactor; .NET can't use your type if it uses a base-class or interface it can't resolve; so it will need the assembly reference.

Comment: Youre directly into my issue here. If EF Isn't a DAL, would Linq2SQL go same way? And what do I lose in thinking of n-Tier app, to disassemble current DAL (DataSets)? IoC is a familiar in theory, but i have to understand better how I would solve this scenario with IoC?

Comment: @dingir L2S is closer to the DB than EF. Note that EF can work with POCO objects - maybe look at POCO with EF...

Comment: Thank's for clarify that. POCO is exactly what screaming out the reference right now. Maybe I missunderstand the code usage for a ef 2 POCO? On other hand people crucifies the use of EF as DAL (following by poco in BL, i think?)..

Comment: I'm clear with that.. I still about figuring out how to keep the flexibility with most maintanable (read minimal) code? I fully clear that there needs a poco for each business logic (read corresponding table object) but it should also be of good design. how would you do one simple poco with this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

> it screams for a missing reference to DAL (where the entity framework belongs).

Ah - no, The EntityFramework IS NOT A DAL. It is a business object runtime. it CONTAINS a DAL, but it basically spawns moer than one tier.

It is totally ok to expose it further up as it is a runtime for business obejcts.

If you use the EntityFramework purely as a DAL this is a questionable usage.

Comment: This topic is one of the most confusing I ever ranned into.. in terms of proposed architecture, code usage  and third party / design tools. I just want it FLEXIBLE (Which EF/Linq2sql are), CODE REUSE and 3-TIER! :).